# Relations between diffeomorphism symmetry theories and invariant $SU(N), N \rightarrow \infty$ theories

Tags: string-theory, gauge-theory, group-theory, field-theory, diffeomorphism-invariance

Is it possible to have, an exhaustive panorama (as much as possible), about the relations between theories having a diffeomorphism symmetry, and theories having a $SU(N), N\rightarrow\infty$  invariance ?

Answer (score 4):

I cannot quite vouch for exhaustive panoramas, but the crucial point is that *GL(N), SU(N)* matrices are representable in a nonhermitean basis discovered by Sylvester in 1882, the [clock and shift 
matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices#Construction:_The_clock_and_shift_matrices) which he called nonions for *N*=3 (*long* before the Gell-Mann basis!), sedenions, etc. Their braiding relations, and maximal grading, and hence commutators, structure constants, and Casimirs!, are thus analytic in *N* and hence handily amenable to the *N⟶∞* limit.

They undergird a discrete truncation of the Heisenberg group explored by Weyl in 1927, but that is almost besides the point, except for the fact that, in a toroidal phase space, they can be organized to SU(N) generators with two integer indices, cf. a [quarter-century old talk of mine](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/9tahoe.pdf) which also does the  SU(∞) gauge theory.

That is to say, the Moyal algebra on a toroidal phase space amounts to *SU(N)*, through Fourier transformation. And the classical, ħ⟶0, limit of that algebra, which is the Poisson-Bracket algebra is thus a Fourier-transform description of SU(∞), an observation first made on the sphere by Hoppe, but made manifest on the torus here.

The above summary talk bird-eye-views an expansive panoramas implicit in [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370269389914184) ; [and here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0370269389910575) ;[and](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/jmp/31/5/10.1063/1.528788) ;
 [available at](https://www.academia.edu/10230700/INFINITE-DIMENSIONAL_ALGEBRAS_SINE_BRACKETS_AND_SU_) ; [and](https://www.academia.edu/6176948/Trigonometric_structure_constants_for_new_infinite-dimensional_algebras) ; [and 
finally](https://www.academia.edu/6688013/InfiniteDimensional_Algebras_and_a_Trigonometric_Basis_for_the_Classical_Lie_Algebras) with apologies for the massive document dump.

Now the Poisson-bracket algebra describes area-preserving diffeomorphisms on a notional phase space, and as such it lends itself to connecting this  SU(∞) to the null string of Schild, basically with the Nambu action squared.  Intriguingly, it has found applications in 2d hydrodynamics and the systematic study of Casimirs, also in use in large-N models in QFT, and the predictable supersymmetrization of such.